# Running one montor on i7 graphics and 1 on discrete graphics

Tags: display, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a Gigabyte Z77X-UD5H with an i7 and a nvidia gtx 670.  Is there anyway to have the i7's graphics run one monitor and the 670 run another?

Comment: exactly what os are you using?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  The 670 support multiple monitors.  You really DO NOT want to do this.

Comment: Windows 7 and running 2 from the 670 lowers my frame rate a lot

Comment: @user145632 - What you want to do will lower it even more.  The fastest graphics card will be lowered to the speed of the slowest.

Comment: @Ramhound Negative. I have similar setup and I'm pretty sure the integrated graphics on my i7 isn't capable of producing the framerates I see in my games. It won't lower it even more, but I don't think it'll fix his problem. This is only useful for getting around the 2 independent display limitation on nVidia cards. Maybe if he's running the games in fullscreen, but even then I don't know. The GTX670 will still be doing composting for both monitors.

Answer (score 1):

If your motherboard supports it, you will want to go into the BIOS and look for iGPU or similar to enable the settings. This will allow both graphic cards to be used.

My rig at home is doing the same thing. I have 4 monitors hooked up to a Radeon HD 6970 CF and a smaller monitor using the integrated graphics. Movie and/or Music is on the iGPU where as my productivity stuff is driven by the Radeon.